# Perforce: how to see original version of file?

Tags: perforce

`p4 filelog foo`
tells me that:

`... #1 change 123456 add on 2014/03/02 by bar@bar_dev (text) 'yada yada'`

How do I display the contents of `foo` as it was when it was added?

Answer (score 2):

```
p4 print foo#1
```

Or:

```
p4 sync foo#1
cat foo
```

Or:

```
p4 print -o foo.tmp foo
cat foo.tmp
```

Generally I'd just use "p4 sync" so I can view the file in my favorite editor/viewer rather than have it dumped to the console, I can compile it, etc -- when you want to go back to the latest version just "p4 sync" again without the "#1".